# Token-based Authentication - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to generate a User and Admin login page.  I followed the instructions contained in the following link. https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/ruby-ruby-on-rails/token-based-authentication-with-ruby-on-rails-5-api  What does api-only app mean?

Answer (score 0):

In normal applications the web pages will be generated and given to browsers. The api-only apps the views will be generated by client apps which runs on browsers. The front-end frameworks will helps you to generate the page according to the data provided from server usually JSON.  If you are creating applications which runs on web and other platform specific apps, then you have to create API's using which you can run single app server which serves request independent of platform. You can dive deep into architectures like REST, frameworks like Angular, Backbone, React.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation.  So, how do I get the api-only to work on my Rails 5 app?

Comment: rails is a framework which helps you, you have to take inputs as JSON and provide output as JSON.

Comment: Let me clarify.  I used the steps in the link to but when I run it I'm not seeing the api being created.

Comment: use rails generator. rails generate scaffold <api-name>

Answer (score 0):

Here the complete guide.

[Using Rails for API-only Applications](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/api_app.html)

Update:
For JWT auth I will recommend to use [Knock](https://github.com/nsarno/knock). This is tested and simple solution.

Comment: Thanks.  i just need to know how to get Token-based Authentication to work using the link i provided above.  Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'll check that out; thanks very much for your time.